# FreeRtos problems in ADC task and Streaming Task

Tags: c, freertos, rtos

I have an ADC task that uses 4 channels and uses the DMA for transfer I also have a streaming client which streams the ADC data through the TCP socket I made the ADS Task lower priority than the streaming client.

I'm sending an integer that selects which ADC channel is selected as a message queue to the streaming client.

The problem is I get queue overflow when sending that adc channel integer.

**ADC TASK**

```
if(bufferSelect != BUFFERS_NOT_READY)
        {
            if(xQueueSend(g_adcQueue, &bufferSelect,  0) != pdPASS)
            {
                throwError(ERROR_MESSAGE_QUEUE_FULL);
                PRINTF("%s\r\n", getErrorMessage(ERROR_MESSAGE_QUEUE_FULL));
            }
            bufferSelect = BUFFERS_NOT_READY;
        }
```

**Streaming client task**

```
/* obtain next buffer ready event */
        if(xQueueReceive(g_adcQueue, &bufferSelect, 0) == pdFALSE)
        {
            g_stopStreaming = true;
            continue;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to handle the queue full status as an error, which it normally isn't - One of the purposes of queues is to back-pressure the producer, and that is exactly what you should do here: If the streaming task cannot digest the data you are throwing at it, you are simply producing too much.

The priority of the consumer does only help keeping queue fill state at a reasonable level when there is no inactive (waiting for I/O) periods in the consumer code. As soon as you have such wait periods in your consumer, priority alone doesn't relieve you from accepting that queues can become full.

Comment: so how would I fix that issue please ?

Comment: Simply don't have the producer produce more than the consumer can accept and digest. Build a pause in the ADC task or lower the sample frequency (or increase Ethernet bandwidth...). For intermittent congestion in the consumer, an increase of the queue capacity might help.

Comment: I have found that the DMA is faster than the ADC task, so I lowered the sampling frequency, and it worked.. but I need a higher sampling rate, is there a better solution ?

Comment: Measure the sustainable bandwidth your ethernet streaming task can achieve in wherever it pushes the data to - You simply cannot produce more than that. Otherwise increase streaming bandwidth - What goes in, must go out..

Comment: I will lower the sampling frequency of the ADC

Comment: the sampling rate of the ADC is 125KHz, and I'm just sending one byte, that's not much data, why I get overflow then ?

Comment: should I add tick delay in while sending the queue like 10 ticks + lowering the DMA frequency sampling ?

Comment: Are you sure you are actually sending only 1 byte? Very probably, you don't. The network stack will collect and packetize data and send much larger chunks. This most probably blocks the streaming task and your queue spills over. In this case, you could maybe try to increase the queue capacity.